# Updated to Xcode 4.2 and can´t run projects in 4.3 simulator

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios-4.2, xcode4.2, ios4

I ´ve just updated to Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5 and my older projects run OK on iPhone iOS 5 simulator , but I can´t run it on iOS 4.3 simulator or in my iPhone 3G 4.2.1. The application crash.

What can I do?, I´m starting to think it was not a good idea to update!

sorry for my english.

Program received signal: SIGABRT

Console:
2011-11-01 09:14:05.555 Romanos[1351:f203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key numero.'

Comment: Is there an error message in the console?

Comment: this is the console :
2011-11-01 09:14:05.555 Romanos[1351:f203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<RomanosViewController 0x5751f40> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key numero.'

Comment: but it worked in Xcode 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That normally means that one of your XIBs container a reference to an `IBOutlet` called `numero` that no longer exists (or has been renamed, or is being referenced on the wrong object). You need to find and delete the reference from your XIB.

I'd look at RomanosViewController's XIB first. :)

Answer (score 0):

It could be what Benjie Gillam said, but also make sure your view controllers are set to the correct classes.

You can check in the interface builder. For example, click on File's Owner or the tab's view controller in a Tab Bar app, and look at the Identity Inspector (command + option + 3). You should select the view controller's class.

Comment: I think there is something with this line, when I comment it the program runs without errors but nothing appear on the screen.     
    //self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}